# Text manipulation via java

Tags: java, file

I am supposed to read a text file via Java and blank out all the e-mail ids and URLs in the text file. This is to reduce noise in the data.

Are there any library functions in java to do the same?

Comment: Nope, I am in the process of smoothing out data to feed into a machine learning system.

Comment: What do you mean by "blank out"? And what do you call an "e-mail id"?

Comment: Remove all the e-mail ids present in the text (a@b.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file in using a FileInputStream and/or a BufferedReader. You can parse each line and use a regex to see if there are any matches for email or URL patterns, and create a new output string or stream to write them out.

Show us what you've tried and your current code.

As an addendum, I've used these:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html
http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls

With varying degrees of success.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in an NLP system the text will be tokenized, and dealing with URLs or email addresses is just one case of reducing low-frequency tokens to placeholders to reduce data sparsity. Assuming that the tokenization is competent to keep each item in one token, it's easier to replace tokens -- in just the same way that you might replace all words that occur less than some threshold with a placeholder.

Further, you might want to apply  Baum-Welch to this whole business.

Answer (score 0):

String.replace() takes a regex and replacement string (in your case ""). Use regex for email fields and urls to accomplish this task.